# code for executing an SQL FUNCTION (not SP and ) in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

i have a function (not a stored procedure) in DB which returns 0/1. How can I retrieve this value in C#?

```
ALTER function dbo.code
(@_code  INT)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @result bt
    IF EXISTS (
           SELECT fld_code
           FROM   client.TBL_Table(NOLOCK)
           WHERE  code = @_code
                  AND used = 0
       )
        SET @result = 1
    ELSE
        SET @result = 0

    RETURN @result
END
```

Comment: @walther - hello, this is what happens when stressed at hurried jobs and wanted to get a quicker answer when you are hurried up. I have waited for the searcher to show me something before I posted, but somehow it didn't, so...here we are. Pls don't down, I really need this account. Thanks

Comment: @JMK - hello, this is what happens when stressed at hurried jobs and wanted to get a quicker answer when you are hurried up. I have waited for the searcher to show me something before I posted, but somehow it didn't, so...here we are. Pls don't down, I really need this account. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will get you some return value from your function.  Make sure you add:

```
using System.Data.SqlClient
```

to your document.

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(yourConnectionString))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new (SqlCommand("SELECT [dbo].[code] as returnValue", conn))
{
    conn.open();
    var returnValue = cmd.ExecuteReader() as int;
    //Do something with your value
}
```

For more information on `SqlConnection` strings, check [SQL Connection Strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Create a command with the following query

`SELECT [dbo].[code] as No`

Then use the SqlDataReader, to read the returned value.